# How to copy a file to a subdirectory path which is the same for multiple directories?

Tags: bash, cp

I wrote a git commit hook and tested it out in a repo called `myrepo`. I would now like to copy it to all the repos I have in my `~/repos` folder. To do that I tried:

```
$ cd ~/repos/myrepo/.git/hooks
$ cp prepare-commit-msg ~/repos/*/.git/hooks
```

When I run this the `cp` errors with the following message on each directory in `repos`:

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory <directory-name>
```

I'm 100% sure `prepare-commit-msg` is not a directory. Why is `cp` complaining that I'm not using `-r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is probably the tool you're looking for.  You can use it to find each directory that is named `hooks` and resides under your `~/repos/` folder.  For each such directory that `find` locates, you tell it to copy your file there.

This will cause one error message for the `myrepo` repo when it tries to copy a file to itself, but that error can be ignored.

```
cd ~/repos/myrepo/.git/hooks
find ~/repos/ -type d -name hooks -exec cp -vp prepare-commit-msg {} \;
```

This command can be improved to handle cases of odd characters in directories or filenames, but that's the gist of it.

As for why your original `cp` command doesn't work, there's probably a question that explains it better, but it's because the shell expands your command to become:

```
cp prepare-commit-msg ~/repos/repo_A/.git/hooks ~/repos/repo_B/.git/hooks ~/repos/repo_C/.git/hooks ~/repos/repo_D/.git/hooks ~/repos/repo_E/.git/hooks
```

and given that syntax, `cp` thinks that you want it to copy the file `prepare-commit-msg` and four directories `~/repos/repo_A/.git/hooks` through `~/repos/repo_D/.git/hooks` and place all of the copied files/directories in `~/repos/repo_E/.git/hooks`.  That is NOT what you want to do, of course, but `cp` is telling you that it won't copy directories recursively unless you use the `-r` option.

If you want to structure your solution somewhat like your original syntax, you could use:

```
cd ~/repos/myrepo/.git/hooks
dirs=( ~/repos/*/.git/hooks )
for d in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    cp -vp prepare-commit-msg "$d/"
done
```

[Methods which involve parsing the output of `ls` are not recommended.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: Would you happen to know why the cp command is breaking? Why isn't the '*' filling in all files under ~/repos?

Comment: @justaguy Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `cp` with your own `cp2dirs`:

```
function cp2dirs(){
  from="$1";shift
  [ -f "$from" ] && while (($#)); do cp "$from" "$1/"; shift; done
}
```

Then `cp2dirs prepare-commit-msg ~/repos/*/.git/hooks` does